# Hibernate "The resource type Session does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable"

Tags: java, hibernate, session, extends, implements

I want to use construction

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
...
try (Session session){

}
```

How can I do that?
Because "The resource type Session does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable"

I know, that I need to extend Session and override AutoCloseable method, but when I've try to do that, there is error "The type Session cannot be the superclass of SessionDAO; a superclass must be a class"

**Update**

I've wrote my own DAO framework, but will be use Spring for that

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016299/does-java-have-a-using-statement

Comment: May, I know why are you doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041170/how-to-make-use-of-try-catch-and-resource-statement-for-closing-the-connection

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use a much more solid session/transaction handling infrastructure, like Spring offers you. This way you can use the Same Session across multiple DAO calls and the transaction boundary is explicitly set by the @Transactional annotation.

If this is for a test project of yours, you can use [a simple utility](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-minimal-configuration-for-testing-hibernate/) like this one:

```
protected <T> T doInTransaction(TransactionCallable<T> callable) {
    T result = null;
    Session session = null;
    Transaction txn = null;
    try {
        session = sf.openSession();
        txn = session.beginTransaction();

        result = callable.execute(session);
        txn.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if ( txn != null && txn.isActive() ) txn.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
final Long parentId = doInTransaction(new TransactionCallable<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long execute(Session session) {
            Parent parent = new Parent();
            Child son = new Child("Bob");
            Child daughter = new Child("Alice");
            parent.addChild(son);
            parent.addChild(daughter);
            session.persist(parent);
            session.flush();
            return parent.getId();
        }
});
```

Check this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-master-class) for more examples like this one.